# what can i delete from ext folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs

So, my question is.. I download ext folder from extjs.com, and i delete from there folder called welcome & docs. what else can i delete from ext folder? maybe examples? But if i delete some icons are dissappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you make a very very standar extjs app(not include ext.ux etc)

my previous project is using extjs v3...
and my structure folder is like this :

```
htdocs
   +-----resources
   |        +--- css
   |        +--- images
   |
   +--------js
   |        `--- ext-all.js
   |        `--- ext-base.js
   `--index.html
```

or in other word, i delete all folder(exept resources), but move the ext-base.js from `adapter/ext/` to `js` folder.. and also move ext-all.js to this one...

so my html looks like this:

```
....
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-all.js"></script>
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using ExtJS 3.x version,

If icons are disappearing, it means, you are referring to some files in the examples directory from your page (probably examples.css?)

You should be able to get rid of

- subfolders in adapter (Except the
  adapter you are using. most likely
  ext)
- docs
- examples (looking at your post you probably need examples/shared folder)
- pkgs
- src
- test
- welcome
- docs examples pkgs src test